# Changing Internet connection on ISA Server 2000

Tags: firewall, proxy, isa-server, windows-sbs

We are getting a new internet connection installed and will need to unplug the old one and connect this to our ISA Server 2000.

Will this be a simple swap out job? We will be given a new ip, which i know i will have to enter into the external network card TCP/IP page. I will also be given the default gateway to enter.

The ISP engineer said we may have to reset the ARP? cache, if we dont know how we will have to reset the ISA server? Has anyone any experience?

The current connection is with the same ISP but it was owned by the business park were we are located and they linked up an ethernet port to what i assume is their own router.

Hope you can help, i know that ISA 2000 is somewhat less easy to use than the newer versions.

Answer (score 1):

Is that ISA publishing services on the external network, or is it only used as an outgoing firewall?

If you are publishing services, you will need to reconfigure all your rules to use the new external IP address.

Comment: Its just used as a proxy server/firewall to protect our network.

Comment: Then just change the TCP/IP settings on the external network card, and you'll be fine. A server restart also will probably help, I'd to it hust to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

Provided you change your IP address on the NIC, then you shouldn't have any problems. Personally, I would reboot the server just to be safe.